# Stationary wave on a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves

The problem says:

> *A string lies on the x-axis, and is fixed at $ x=-a $ and $ x=a $. At $ t=0 $ we impose a transversal velocity given by $ a^2-x^2 $. Assuming that the velocity of the wave is $ c $, find the solution to the wave equation.*

So here's what I did so far:
I set up the solution in complex form as $$ \tilde{y}(x,t) = \tilde{A}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}+\tilde{B}e^{i(-kx-\omega t)} $$
Then imposing the condition of fixed string, I got the values for $ k_n =\frac{n \pi}{2a} $ and $\omega_n =\frac{n \pi}{2a}c $

In the process I got the relation $\tilde{A}=-\tilde{B}e^{2ka}$

Now my problem is when I plug back into the original equation, I get something like this:
$$ \tilde{y}(x,t)=\tilde{B}e^{-i\omega_n t}(e^{ik_nx} -e^{i(k_nx + 2k_na)})$$

I know that $2k_na=n\pi$, but that gives me two possible results for $e^{i2k_na}$, 1 and -1. That confuses me a bit, and I don't know how to continue from here.
I've seen the example of the plucked string that goes from 0 to $L$, and that's much simpler than this case. I guess I just don't know what to do with the constants introduced by the fact that the string goes from $-a$ to $a$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the intital condition, what does "a transverse velocity given by $a^2-x^2$" mean?  The units (position squared) don't make much sense.